# Ruby on Rails app deployed to heroku but Application error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

everyone actually i am new to ROR and struggling with debugging and especially reading and understanding heroku logs

I am using cloud 9 as an ide for development

I have made a basic note app and after successful build i deployed it to heroku but when i open the app link it says application error

can someone please help me out thank you !

Ruby version

```
ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-linux]
```

Rails version

```
Rails 4.2.5
```

Gemfile

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

  ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Heroku logs -n 300

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-evm_rnjGHiblHGckLmGwGcmOv5yBd6-/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: It *might* help if you add your ruby and rails version to your question.

Comment: This warnings appear because you are using `ruby 2.4.0`. Update the version of `Rails` and it should work fine.

Comment: updated question with ruby and rails version

Comment: Share your _Gemfile_ and the output of  `heroku logs -n 300` command.

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin i have added gemfile content and also provided the heroku logs thanks for your response

Comment: Try adding `ruby '2.5.1'` after the `source` line in your _Gemfile_. Git add, git commit and `git push heroku master`. If it still doesn't work, share the `heroku logs -n 300` again. Use Pastebin to share logs. Don't use GDrive.

Comment: thanks i have added ruby version to gem file and also updated gem file content above so you can see it. Moreover, its still not working and shows application error

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin [3 warnings upon typing -> git push heroku master] https://pastebin.com/QjLX9wYj

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin [output of heroku -n 300 logs] https://pastebin.com/JHVHwhgG

Comment: I have a feeling that this issue is related to your Rails version. After checking Rails gems list, I saw `4.2.10` is the last maintained version for 4.2.x family - https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/4.2.10 - can you try upgrade to 4.2.10 (change the line in your Gemfile), run `bundle install`, run `gem install bundler`, git add, commit and push it to Heroku again.

Comment: thanks guys ! Sometimes the solution is really simple but it can't be sensed. I solved the issue just by adding version of pg gem in group production [gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'].

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin you helped me a lot here is the link for my first ever ROR app can u have a look on it and provide me some useful feedback relating it. https://milestone-notes-app.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys ! Sometimes the solution is really simple but it can't be sensed. I solved the issue just by adding version of pg gem in group production [gem 'pg', '~> 0.20']